# why is python sendall sending last byte twice?

Tags: python, modbus

I'm using Python 2.7.5 to send a message to a modbus tcp simulator. What I do not understand is why python is sending the last byte twice on sendall:

This is what the python script prints out per my code (below)...

```
S: 00020000000c1110000400030600790083008d
R: 000200000006111000040003
R: 8d0000000003d8f603
```

The simulator logs this where (TX is received from script and RX is sent to script)...

```
TX: 00020000000c1110000400030600790083008d
RX: 000200000006111000040003
TX: 8d
Modbus message in error x03
RX: 8d0000000003d8f603
```

So question is...why is 8d sent twice (according to the modbus simulator listening)? The simulator is throwing an error because of it...
Code excerpt:

```
def writeMultipleHoldingRegister(socket, transactionid, unitid, address,valuesToWrite):
    TRANSACT_ID_BYTES = convertIntToBytes(int(transactionid))
    DATA_ADDRESS_BYTES = convertIntToBytes(int(address))
    FUNCTIONCODE_BYTES = '10'
    NUMREGISTERS_BYTES = convertIntToBytes(len(valuesToWrite))
    NUMBYTES = len(valuesToWrite)*2
    NUMBYTES_BYTES = str(('%04X' % NUMBYTES)[2:4])
    MESSAGE_LENGTH_BYTES = convertIntToBytes(int(6+(len(valuesToWrite)*2)))
    modbustcp_write = (TRANSACT_ID_BYTES + '0000' + MESSAGE_LENGTH_BYTES + unitid + FUNCTIONCODE_BYTES + DATA_ADDRESS_BYTES + NUMREGISTERS_BYTES + NUMBYTES_BYTES).decode('hex')
    for value in valuesToWrite:
        modbustcp_write = modbustcp_write + convertIntToBytes(int(value)).decode('hex')
    print 'S:', binascii.hexlify(modbustcp_write)
    socket.sendall(modbustcp_write) #modbus tcp
    data = socket.recv(12)
    print 'R:', binascii.hexlify(data)

    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 502
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    writeMultipleHoldingRegister(s, 2, '11', 4, [121, 131, 141])
    print 'R:', binascii.hexlify(s.recv(100))
    s.close()
```

Followed advice left in comment. Process Monitor showed me the traffic but not the bytes themselves. So I downloaded and ran RawCAP and viewed the output in Wireshark. To paraphrase...where 'S' is sent by simulator and 'R' is received by simulator...

```
R: 00020000000c1110000400030600790083008d (modbus request recv)
S: 000200000006111000040003 (modbus ack good request sent)
S: 8d0000000003d8f603 (modbus error notification sent...wtf)
```

I never see a '8d' received twice...so I don't know what's going on here. Maybe a bug in the simulator... http://www.plcsimulator.org/

Comment: Use `strace` (Linux) or Process Monitor (Windows) to verify that Python is actually sending `8d` twice.

Comment: What Ross said.  And, note the '\x8d' is suspicious, as it's the Return character (ASCII 13, 0x0d) with the high bit set.  Is anything `print()`ing to the stream?

Comment: this part is odd `for value in valuesToWrite:
        modbustcp_write = ...` what's the point in reassigning `modbustcp_write` several times? it only gets sent out once, thus other `value`'s are lost.